# Block an unexpected popup with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am automating an e-commerce website but I am getting an unexpected random popup on any page. If I know that a popup will fire on a given web page, I can handle it. What do I do if it randomly occurs on any page?

[image]

I know how to block a popup but can't use that in this situation. Due to this popup, my scripts are failing. HTML code:

```
<div class="acsClassicInner" role="document">
    <div class="acsLogoSpacer">
        <img src="//gateway.foresee.com/sites/barneys/staging/trigger/sitelogo.gif" class="acsSiteLogo" title="" alt="">
        <img src="https://static.foresee.com/logos/foresee/150_67.png" class="acsNoDisplay" title="ForeSee" alt="ForeSee">
        <div title="ForeSee" alt="ForeSee" class="acsVendorLogoSVG"></div>
    </div>
    <h1 id="fsrHeading">We'd welcome your feedback!</h1>
    <p>Thank you for visiting Barneys.com. You have been selected to participate in a brief customer satisfaction survey to let us know how we can improve your experience.</p>
    <p class="acsNoticeAboutSurvey">The survey is designed to measure your entire experience, please look for it at the <u>conclusion</u> of your visit.</p>
    <p class="acsAttribution">This survey is conducted by an independent company ForeSee, on behalf of the site you are visiting.</p>
    <a href="#" tabindex="2" class="acsInviteButton acsDeclineButton" title="No, thanks" role="button" precog_scanned="true">No, thanks</a>
    <a id="acsFocusFirst" tabindex="3" href="about:blank" target="_blank" class="acsInviteButton acsRightButton acsAcceptButton" title="Yes, I'll give feedback (Opens in a new window)" role="button" precog_scanned="true">Yes, I'll give feedback</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into EventFiringWebDriver and WebDriverEventListener, and look for the popup in question> lets say the popup occurs after a button click, you can look for it in beforeClickOn and if it does occur do an action, else don't do anything.

Sorry I dont have any Java EventFiringWebDriver code snippets to share

http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/index.html

code from selenium github

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.events import EventFiringWebDriver, AbstractEventListener
class MyListener(AbstractEventListener):
    def before_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("Before navigate to %s" % url)
    def after_navigate_to(self, url, driver):
        print("After navigate to %s" % url)

 driver = Firefox()
 ef_driver = EventFiringWebDriver(driver, MyListener())
 ef_driver.get("http://www.google.co.in/")
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a helping method with the following pseudo code:-
    1. Check if there's a pop up.
    2. If it finds pop up, then handle it.
    3. If not, then return.

Now use this function in your script every time whenever there's a change in the content on the screen due to some action.

Comment: The problem is I have to use this method on every click which is making the code complicated. And I have to use this trick again and again on every click.